# GenericSync event not initialising on view - Famo.us

Tags: famo.us

I have a view (tribeProduct) that generates a list of surfaces that are contained in a scroll view, what I want to do is a create an event that when the view is "dragged" down, an animation comes into play. The following is what I have so far that for some reason isn't working.

```
for (var t = 0; t < tribesLength; t++) {
    var tribe = new TribesView({tribes: tribes, tribe: t});

    if(tribes[t]['notifications'] > 0) {
        // Create view with list of surfaces contained in a scroll view
        var tribeProduct = new ProductView({tribes: tribes, tribe: t});
        var productModifier = new Modifier({
            opacity: 0,
            transform: Transform.translate(window.innerWidth * 1, 0, 100)
        });

        productContext.add(productModifier).add(tribeProduct);

        tribe.on('click', function(e) {
            var tribeProduct = this[0];
            var productModifier = this[1];

            productModifier.setOpacity(1, { duration: 500 });
            productModifier.setTransform(Transform.translate(0, 0, 100), { duration: 500, curve: Easing.inOutBack });

            var handleSwipe = new GenericSync(
                ['mouse', 'touch'],
                { direction: GenericSync.DIRECTION_Y }
            );

            tribeProduct.pipe(handleSwipe);

            handleSwipe.on('end', (function(data) {
                console.log('test');
                var position = data.position;
                var startPos = 100;

                if(position > startPos) {
                    this
                        .setOpacity(
                            0, { duration: 500, curve: 'easeInOut' }
                        )
                        .setTransform(
                            Transform.translate(0, startPos + 200, 0), { duration: 500, curve: 'easeInOut' }
                        );
                }
                console.log(position);
            }).bind(productModifier));
        }.bind([tribeProduct, productModifier]));
    }

    tribe.pipe(scrollView);
    surfaces.push(tribe);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar question it was targeted at a pull to refresh but it answers your questions as well. Or at least I believe it does.

[Scrollview Pull to Refresh Famo.us](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24527713/scrollview-pull-to-refresh-famo-us/24567079#24567079)

Using John Traver's response I came up with the refreshScrollView:

https://github.com/vizidrix/famous

If you look at the code I think it will help.